# Highcharts Non-Identical Time Series

Tags: php, highcharts

I have a collection of arrays representing non-identical time series:

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => 
      [2014-01-08] => 1408
      [2014-01-09] => 1357
      [2014-01-10] => 1272
      [2014-01-11] => 1625
      [2014-01-12] => 1516
      [2014-01-13] => 2002
      [2014-01-14] => 2301
  )
  Array
  (
      [0] => 
      [2014-01-21] => 32
      [2014-01-22] => 234
      [2014-01-23] => 195
      [2014-01-24] => 176
      [2014-01-25] => 231
      ...
```

I want to display this data in a HighCharts `linechart`.

I know this can be done by the documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/.

If I disregard that the periods are non-identical, I can create a plot with Highroller:

```
foreach(array_keys($arrays) as $campaign_name) {
  $data = array_values($arrays[$campaign_name]);

  $series[$campaign_name] = new HighRollerSeriesData();
  $series[$campaign_name]->addName($campaign_name)->addData($data);
}
```

But all the lines in this charts start a x = 0.

I then tried creating a syntex similar to the `jsfiddle` above, but the plot does not render:

```
foreach(array_keys($arrays) as $campaign_name) {
  $data = array_values($arrays[$campaign_name]);
  $dates = array_keys($arrays[$campaign_name]);

  $data = array_combine($dates, $data);

  $series[$campaign_name] = new HighRollerSeriesData();
  $series[$campaign_name]->addName($campaign_name)->addData($data);
}
```

Comment: `[0] => ` It probably will create issue, since it's adding point with index=0, so it will draw chart starting from 0, right?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is not the issue. The empty `[0] => ` gets translated into a `false` and is not drawn.

Comment: Could you attach how is your data displayed after translation to JS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data and then modify it to `timestamp` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/NHnkQ/

```
    myDataSeries1 = [
        ["2014-01-08", 1408],
        ["2014-01-09", 1357],
        ["2014-01-10", 1272],
        ["2014-01-11", 1625],
        ["2014-01-12", 1516],
        ["2014-01-13", 2002],
        ["2014-01-14", 2301]
    ];

    myDataSeries2 = [
        ["2014-01-21", 32],
        ["2014-01-22", 234],
        ["2014-01-23", 195],
        ["2014-01-24", 176],
        ["2014-01-25", 231]
    ];

    $.each(myDataSeries1, function (index, item) {
        item[0] = new Date(item[0]).getTime();
    });

    $.each(myDataSeries2, function (index, item) {
        item[0] = new Date(item[0]).getTime();
    });

... /// Further down 

        series: [{
            name: 'MyData1',
            data: myDataSeries1
        }, {
            name: 'MyData2',
            data: myDataSeries2
        }]
```